# How much higher is the wave drag for a spaceplane compared to its induced drag

Tags: trajectory, atmospheric-drag, spaceplane, shockwave

I'm working on the conceptual design of the path of a suborbital spaceplane and am trying to do basic calculations. I read that wave drag near the sonic barrier can be huge and can impede the flight.

I'm trying to use a Skylon type concept which breathes air till 10-15 km and then rockets from there on. How would one account for wave drag? How does it increase with launch and how would affect re-entry of the vehicle and this would be basically for the earlier air breathing section of the flight. Altitudes 15 km max.

For the uninitiated, there's a nice definition of wave drag in [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-wave-drag-1) that begins

> Wave drag is a kind of aerodynamic drag. This drag comes into picture only when shock wave forms over or in front of the (spaceplane).

See also [Skybrary](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Wave_Drag) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_drag) and [Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=wave+drag).